# Starting the ActiveMQ broker, results in an error

Tags: activemq-classic

I am trying to start the activemq broker on a Windows machine by following the instructions at

http://activemq.apache.org/getting-started.html#GettingStarted-StartingActiveMQ

After downloading the Windows binaries, I changed to the installation directory and launched the broker using bin/activemq as instructed. The launch fails and after scanning the wall of text I found the following error.

```
ERROR | Failed to start Apache ActiveMQ ([localhost, ID:[Computer ID]:1], java.io.IOException:    Transport Connector could not be registered i
n JMX: Failed to bind to server socket: amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1
000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 due to: java.net.BindException: Address al
ready in use: JVM_Bind)
```

The address already in use caused me to believe that another amqp broker, such as RabbitMQ or Qpid(both of which are installed), might have allocated the connection so I restarted my computer but with no success on eliminating the error.

Can anyone give me some ideas on what to try to get ActiveMQ running properly.

Answer (score 8):

Change the amqp port in activemq_home/conf/activemq.xml to something else like 5673 and restart activemq
`<transportConnectors>
            <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="**amqp://0.0.0.0:5673**?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>`

Comment: Works as charm.

Answer (score 1):

I would try running `netstat -anb` from the command prompt and see if you can find something using port 5672.

Answer (score 1):

I would try running netstat -nlp from the command prompt and see if you can find something using port 5672. then use the process-id to kill this process (kill -9 )

Answer (score 1):

Following are some of the basic and important configuration areas one has to look at.If you are seeing the issue then try changing the port mentioned under `activemq.xml` :-

```
<transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:6616?maximumConnection
<transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5673?maximumConnections=1
<transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnection
<transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1
<transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000
<transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:6616?maximumConnection
<transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5673?maximumConnections=1
<transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0`enter code here`.0.0:61613?maximumConnection
<transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1
<transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000
```

Pay attention to the error message. It will specifically tell which port has the bind issue.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that port change works.
In my case port 1883 to 18830, mqqt section :

```
name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883
```

I simply added zero at the port end like this :

```
name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:18830
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to try.

1. Check to see if the port is blocked by a firewall.
2. Change the AMQP transport connector port to some other value, 5763 etc

There is something on your system blocking access to that port, a running service, firewall etc.